# iOS: how to make an interface cannot be instantiated?

Tags: objective-c, ios

First I designed a protocol as my base class, which could not be instantiated. Later I found there should be some shared methods between classes conformed to this protocol, so I'd like to add some *default implementation* to the protocol.
AFAIK, Obj-C doesn't support protocol with default behaviors so I have to make it an interface. Then came up with my question, how to make an interface cannot be instantiated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces can't be instantiated, ever. Maybe you're thinking about abstract classes, which aren't really available in Objective-C. Maybe you should rethink your program structure and try to use more inheritance. If the class you are inheriting from conforms to a certain protocol ( which is somewhat of the Objective-C equivalent of Java Interfaces ), then you can instantiate that, or subclass it and then instantiate it.

Have a look here for more information about inheritance: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about similar abstract classes (not interfaces) in Java. Restructuring my inheritance, adding a base interface conforming to a certain protocol, and having all other subclasses extend from this base interface is a solution indeed. However, I didn't understand 'Interfaces can't be instantiated, ever', they do can be instantiated. I'm talking about Obj-C terms right here.

Comment: Ah yes, you probably mean the /@interface syntax in Obejctive-C right? If compared to Java that would be the class identifier. The naming is different because you declare the interface first, in the header file and the /@implementation second, in the implementation file. Basically, you declare a class like you do in C++, only you call the header the interface, because that's what it is most of the time; A definition of what the class implementation must implement.

Comment: Sure, I meant the @interface syntax in Obejctive-C :D. But I still wanna know if it's possible to make an interface cannot be instantiated. Looks like the answer is NO.

Comment: It seems like you're missing a word every time.. Do you want to create an interface that cannot be instantiated? Because the Objective-C equivalent of that are protocols ( compared to for example Java ). Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html

Comment: Sorry, if the question went like 'if protocol can provide default method implementations?', did I make it more clear?